# Too many anchor points in Illustrator artwork

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

Does anybody have a great suggestion to make a piece of artwork with too many points more functional in Illustrator? We have tried making the artwork a brush, a symbol, etc., but replicating the artwork (trees, bushes) a few hundred times in the layout piece makes for an enormous, dysfunctional file. See jpg to help explain what I mean.
[image]

Comment: Will you be duplicating the *same* few trees many times?

Comment: [Relevant answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/118423/63979), not a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

I don't *think* the bush example on the left can be *significantly* improved (other than the flowers) and keep its qualities, *but I think the one on the **right*** could *easily* be improved ***a ton*** - the basic leaf shape there could be managed with half the anchorpoints or less, and still have significantly the same feel - *especially* if there won't be a deep-zoom-in close look at the leaf-element level: one assumes from your symbols & brushes attempt that the intent is to have a lot of these - like a siteplan or a decorative motif.

I'd grab all the leaves on a copy of the right one, and run the **Object>Path>Simplify** tool and see how many anchorpoints you can lose whilst keeping your same basic feel: I'm guessing you can cut your anchorpoints by as much as 75% whilst keeping that look. I'd do the same to the flowers on the left-hand bush, BTW.

[image]

The tool gives you a live preview of the impact of your impending edit, and a rough estimate of the impact on the anchorpoint-count on the given item. I'd do one leaf first as a tester, and provided you're OK with the results, move on.

[image]

As you can see, less than half the anchorpoints and still enough of the same shape and feel to pass muster - and my initial anchorpoint density was about a tenth of your right bush. 
[image]

**If** the viewer will ***never*** see the leaves close-up, they should really be held by *only 4 anchorpoints* - that's all they should need for a basic elongated / tapered ellipse.

Only ***after*** you've done this type of cleanup to all your art would I make my symbols of these - and yes, I would do that for sure: **symbols** will *really* help keep your filesize down.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No matter how simple the shapes are, once you clone it hundreds of times - you end up with massive path volume which decreases performance. Best is to simplify the path and definitely utilize symbols.

Comment: @WELZ - yup. I was intending OP set up symbols *after* doing cleanup - I'll add that to my answer for clarity - thanks mate!

Comment: Yes, I should have cleaned up the paths on these. I have done so on others.I've tried making symbols, brushes, converting the artwork to psds, and then some. For site plans, the shear bulk of the replication becomes unmanageable. Then I have to take a wonderful vector file and convert it to a photoshop file to use in printed materials. I'll continue trying to perfect the clean-up/symbols method. But if anybody has found that magic solution, let me know. Thanks to everyone!

Comment: I spent a long time doing illustrative site plans in Illus traitor: my approach is a lot looser, squigglier, and managed via graphic styles: that way, you leave bushes & trees as circles, apply the graphic style and you’re good. Less detailed, yes, but easier to manage on huge files.

Comment: https://cdna.artstation.com/p/assets/images/images/015/816/084/large/gerard-falla-firestation-43-site-plan-01-01.jpg?1549777826

Comment: Thanks Gerard. We're putting together a library of trees and bushes as you described and see how they do when we have to use hundreds of them. In the meantime, one of my co-workers is experimenting with Maya and Vectorworks to see if we can import a more functional set of items. Do you have any experience with "alternate" vector art brought into Illustrator? (At this point, we don't even know if it will work.)

Comment: Eps, svg, pdf, DWG, dxf will all come into illustrator well: from a NURBS modeller you *might* get some really clean vectors - most poly-modelling based apps (CADD included) will probably be right back at a ton of points. You’re best off with four-anchor or two-anchor circles perturbed by graphic styles saved from effects like roughen & tweak at the Appearance-palette level; overlays of multiple fills & strokes w/ tweaks & roughen each a bit different, all applies to the two or four anchor-point circles. You can make sub-shapes like leaves that way too, using the transform effect.